# Typography combination for Georgia

Tags: font-recommendation, font-pairing

I want to use Serif font Georgia. Which Sans Serif fonts go well with Georgia. I am using Impact for my Logo.

Can some one help in identifying a good Sans Serif font that can go well with Headers mainly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check theses links might be one of them will help you to identifying a good Sans Serif font which  can go well with Headers mainly. wherever i know First link have your answer please check.

1. Family [Georgia,Utopia,Palatino,'Palatino Linotype',serif;](http://safalra.com/web-design/typography/web-safe-fonts-myth/)
2. [More fonts like georgia](http://new.myfonts.com/morelike/391/)
3. pick a serif and a sans serif typeface that work well together. This can be tricky to get just right. [Here’s one way to do it:](http://www.bigbrandsystem.com/design-101-7-typographic-resources-and-1-type-joke/)
4. [Common fonts to all versions of Windows & Mac equivalents](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html)
5. Georgia & Verdana [Typefaces
   designed for the screen
   (finally)](http://www.will-harris.com/verdana-georgia.htm)

---

this  Question on same site may help you [popular-serif-and-sans-serif-browser-compatible-font-combinations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/794/popular-serif-and-sans-serif-browser-compatible-font-combinations)

---

I Read your comment [if you need information about Web safe fonts than check this too](http://www.fonttester.com/help/list_of_web_safe_fonts.html)

Answer (score 3):

[image: Arimo Bold 72px]

Indeed I use Georgia as my preferred serif font. My companion sans-serif font stack, which includes the Google font **Arimo** (illustrated above), is

> `"Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, TeXGyreHeros, FreeSans, "Nimbus Sans L", "Liberation Sans", Arimo, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`

except for large **non-italic** headings, for which I insert "Microsoft Sans Serif" ahead of "Liberation Sans". I give my reasons in "[**A multiplatform Helvetica-like font stack that suppresses Arial**](http://www.grputland.com/2013/11/multiplatform-helvetica-like-font-stack.html)".

Answer (score 1):

Try Gotham or Akkurat Pro or Helvetica

Comment: Thanks a lot will try it out.. is any of this web safe font ?

Comment: No. But Helvetica is on all Macs and very similar to (but *not* the same as) Arial on all PCs.

Comment: What did they all smoke to find Helvetica _very similar_ to Arial?!

Comment: @mbx:Where do they differ? Be specific.

Comment: Well, where to start: have a look at the G, R, C, J, a, e, s and c in both fonts, especially on instrokes and outstrokes.

Comment: @mbx: e100 is correct. Typographically-speaking, Arial and Helvetica are very similar. They both belong to the family of Grotesks (Arial was drawn by Monotype, and based on Monotype Grotesque). In weight, proportion and set they are very close. One of the design goals for Arial was that it should read well at low resolutions, which later made it a fairly natural choice as a font for the web. Arial and Helvetica are invariably listed together in <font-family> style definitions. Whether or not you *like* Arial is a matter of taste, not typeface characteristics.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Arial is the ugly twin sister of Helvetica. They share lots of their specifications as they belong to the same family, but "very similiar" is not the phrase. Arial totally okay for low resolution web text. But I wouldn't use it for print or as part of the cd.

Comment: @e100: The most obvious difference is the top of the lower-case "t" - In Helvetica it is flat across, in Arial it slants. The same goes for the ends of the lower-case "s" and Upper & lower "C/c. Also, the UC "R" in Helv rounds down towards the baseline straight-vertical. In Arial it is more of a diagonal towards the next letter. The tail on Arial's UC "Q" has a slight curve to it; in Helv it is a more perfect geometric bar. There are a few other slight variances in the lettershapes but those are the most easily described. Overall Helvetica is more geometric than Arial, and Arial has some sligh